# Somar resultados e exibir separadamente dentro do loop

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber como faço para somar vários resultados.
Estou criando uma aplicação simples para um desafio financeiro particular.
Por exemplo:

```
double salario = 1500;
double desafio;

for(double mes=1; mes<=12; mes++){
    desafio = (salario * mes)/100;
    System.out.println("Valor do Desafio:" + desafio);
}
```

Este código gera como resultado todos os valores mensais que precisam ser "depositados", perfeito. Queria saber como faço para somar todos estes resultados gerados.

Comment: Perfeito.. Posso usar... mas depois de gerar todos os resultados, como faço para somar tudo que gerou?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria isso?

```
double salario = 1500;
double desafio = 0;

for(double mes=1; mes<=12; mes++){
    desafio += (salario * mes)/100;
    System.out.println("Valor do Desafio:" + desafio);
}
```

Isso vai somar os valores anteriores com o atual. Veja funcionando no ideone: https://ideone.com/cxw87K

Se quiser continuar exibindo os valores de cada mês, basta criar uma variável temporária dentro do loop:

```
double salario = 1500;
double desafio = 0;

for(double mes=1; mes<=12; mes++){
    double mesAtual = (salario * mes)/100;
    desafio += mesAtual;
    System.out.println("Valor do Mes Atual:" + mesAtual);
}

System.out.println("Valor do desafio:" + desafio);
```

A saida será:

```
Valor do Mes Atual:15.0
Valor do Mes Atual:30.0
Valor do Mes Atual:45.0
Valor do Mes Atual:60.0
Valor do Mes Atual:75.0
Valor do Mes Atual:90.0
Valor do Mes Atual:105.0
Valor do Mes Atual:120.0
Valor do Mes Atual:135.0
Valor do Mes Atual:150.0
Valor do Mes Atual:165.0
Valor do Mes Atual:180.0
Valor do desafio:1170.0
```

Veja funcionando no ideone: https://ideone.com/N1IKrg

Comment: Este '+=' gerou erro para mim... O que precio é pegar os resultados que gerou no calculo.. e somar tudo...  Creio ser bem simples, mas to confuso ainda

Comment: @MaurícioMaciel não gera erro não, veja: https://ideone.com/cxw87K

Comment: Não amigo.. isto de gerar os valores ele já esta perfeito... mas quando acrescentei o '+=' no eclipse gerou isto:                                      
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The local variable desafio may not have been initialized
 at financeiro.main(financeiro.java:9)

Comment: @MaurícioMaciel você iniciou a variavel desafio? Preste bem atenção no meu código, repare que eu iniciei ela: `double desafio = 0;` Acessa o link e veja que o código funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Sim, vi que iniciou, fiz o mesmo agora e rodou desculpa pela falha... mas veja só... Rode este código aqui (meu code inicial):                                           public class financeiro {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  double salario = 1500;
  double desafio;
  double resultado;
  
  for(double mes=1; mes<=12; mes++){
   desafio = (salario * mes)/100;
   System.out.println("Valor do Desafio:" + desafio);
  }
 }
}            Veja os resultados que geram.. agora veja os resultados que geram com tua sugestão de alteração

Comment: @MaurícioMaciel e qual o problema? Você disse que quer somar todos o valores e no seu código não soma, só exibe o valor da iteração atual do loop.

Comment: Sim, quero somar... Mas quero fazer assim... gerou lá os valores "15, 30, 45, 60..." depois de gerar os 12 meses com seus respectivos valores, quero somar quanto deu.... tipo 15+30+45... eu até poderia criar uma variável 'desafio' para cada mês e somar tudo depois, mas acho que tem outra mais mais correta e simples de fazer.. Se não fui claro, me pergunte por favor.

Comment: Isto... Tipo depois de gerar todos os resultados.. queria uma nova variável para mostrar a soma total de tudo que gerou...

Comment: @MaurícioMaciel isso você não disse na pergunta, por isso é importante fazer a pergunta e explicar exatamente tudo que quer fazer e não apenas um pedaço do problema. Isso é facilmente resolvido criando uma nova variável. Veja a edição na resposta.

Comment: Perdão... pensei que tivesse explicado bem, sou novato por aqui, como já deve ter percebido... Mas tchê 100%, era exatamente isto que precisava, muito grato e novamente desculpa o transtorno. Valeu Dr.

Comment: @MaurícioMaciel funcionou legal agora?

Comment: Perfeitíssimo.. Era isto mesmo que tava quebrando cabeça para completar

Answer (score 0):

Declare e inicialize uma variável para receber o total:

```
double total = 0;
```

para somar os valores use o seguinte comando (dentro do laço):

```
total += desafio;
```

praticamente equivale a `total = total + desafio;`